# Java stream a list and create a single object

Tags: java, java-stream, java-17

I have a list of `Boolean` fields that looks something like this:

```java
var lst = List.of(true, false, false, false);
```

And there is one object like this:

```
public class GetBatchStatusResponse {
  String batchCompleted;
  Integer totalCount;
  Integer processed;
  Integer pending;
}
```

The above object currently getting populated with something like this:

```
var resp = new GetBatchStatusResponse();

resp.setBatchCompleted(String.valueOf( !lst.contains(false));
resp.setTotalCount(lst.size());
resp.setProcessed((int)(lst.stream().filter(p ->p!=null && p == true).count()));
resp.setPending((int)(lst.stream().filter(p ->p==null || p == false).count()));
```

How can the same thing be achieved with the stream API in a single loop?

Comment: to be clear: you want to loop over Boolean list to get resp ? `var resp = lst.stream()...();`

Comment: `p==null && p == false` will throw an NPE if `p==null`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Is `null` _really_ allowed to be present in the list? It seems odd.

Comment: You've got a name mismatch preventing a compilation: `GetBatchResponse` & `GetBatchStatusResponse`.  Can you please edit this question to fix this to consistently use whichever of these two names you prefer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it in what I see as the simplest way:

```
var trueCount = Collections.frequency(lst, true);
var resp = new GetBatchStatusResponse();

resp.setBatchCompleted(String.valueOf(trueCount == lst.size());
resp.setTotalCount(lst.size());
resp.setProcessed(trueCount);
resp.setPending(lst.size() - trueCount);
```

Don't immediately think of streams to solve every conceivable problem, but keep in mind that sometimes there are more useful Collections methods you can use.

Comment: so smart man, compliments !

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `partitioningBy` collector. Use the `counting` collector as the downstream, since you want the count of each group.

```
var partitions = lst.stream().collect(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(
                Boolean.TRUE::equals,
                Collectors.counting()
        )
);
```

Then, you can set the corresponding fields to `partitions.get(true)` and `partitions.get(false)`.

```
resp.setProcessed((int)partitions.get(true));
resp.setPending((int)partitions.get(false));
resp.setBatchCompleted(String.valueOf(partitions.get(false) == 0));
```

Comment: And also `resp.setBatchCompleted(String.valueOf(partitions.get(false) == 0))`

Comment: You can also, as an alternative, do `partitioningBy(Boolean.TRUE::equals)`

Comment: @k314159 Thanks for the suggestions! I missed that the value of `batchCompleted` also needs to loop through `lst`.

Comment: I'd suggest that `partitioningBy(Boolean::booleanValue)` would be a bit more idiomatic than `partitioningBy(Boolean.TRUE::equals)`, if we know there will never be nulls in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a statistic with true/false/null counts. If the list can not contain `null`s (I included it just to be on the safe side), you can remove it to simplify the statistic even more.

I would propose to use [Stream.reduce(identity, accumulator, combiner)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) with a statistics object and build the end result from it.

```
public record BooleanStatistic(int trueCount, int falseCount, int nullCount) {

  public BooleanStatistic merge(BooleanStatistic other) {
    return new BooleanStatistic(trueCount + other.trueCount, falseCount + other.falseCount, nullCount + other.nullCount);
  }

  public BooleanStatistic count(Boolean bool) {
    if (bool == null) {
      return new BooleanStatistic(trueCount, falseCount, nullCount + 1);
    }
    if (bool) {
      return new BooleanStatistic(trueCount + 1, falseCount, nullCount);
    }
    return new BooleanStatistic(trueCount, falseCount + 1, nullCount);
  }

  public int total() {
    return trueCount + falseCount + nullCount;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class RandomStuff {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var lst = List.of(true, false, false, false);
    BooleanStatistic statistic = lst.stream().reduce(new BooleanStatistic(0, 0, 0), BooleanStatistic::count, BooleanStatistic::merge);
    System.out.println(statistic);
    var result = new GetBatchResponse();
    result.setBatchCompleted(String.valueOf(statistic.falseCount() == 0));
    result.setTotalCount(statistic.total());
    result.setProcessed(statistic.trueCount());
    result.setPending(statistic.falseCount());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tbh, @Chaosfire solution is valid and more elegant than mine, but I wrote it and I don't like waste. My propose is using another approach with `java.util.stream.Stream#reduce(T, java.util.function.BinaryOperator<T>)`

The code is self explanatory

```
package org.example;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

public class ReduceBooleanList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Assuming boolean list represent batch result
        List<Boolean> batchResult = List.of(true, false, true, false);

        // To get the status of all batches from a list you need to REDUCE more values to one
        BatchStatus statusOfAllBatches = batchResult.stream()
                // 1st: map the boolean to a BatchResponse that represent the status of single batch
                .map(BatchStatus::new)
                // 2nd: combine the list of BatchResponse to a single pojo, combining values to represent the status of all batches
                .reduce(
                        /* Identity: initial value */ new BatchStatus("true", 0, 0, 0),
                        /* Accumulator: function for combining two values */ BatchStatus::merge
                );
        
        System.out.println(statusOfAllBatches);
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class BatchStatus {
        private String batchCompleted;
        private Integer totalCount;
        private Integer processed;
        private Integer pending;

        public BatchStatus(Boolean result) {
            batchCompleted = String.valueOf(result);
            totalCount = 1;
            processed = result != null && result ? 1 : 0;
            pending = result == null || !result ? 0 : 1;

        }

        public BatchStatus merge(BatchStatus b) {
            batchCompleted = String.valueOf(Boolean.parseBoolean(this.batchCompleted) && Boolean.parseBoolean(b.batchCompleted));
            totalCount += b.getTotalCount();
            processed += b.getProcessed();
            pending += b.getPending();
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```